# VS Code - Intellisense varies

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, intellisense

I have to admit, I am very stumped and must be missing something obvious.

On one user profile on my macbook, VS code works like a dream.  For code like

```
import numpy as np

np.random.
```

I get code help/completion.  FWIW, I am using a conda environment.

When I switch my User to one that I use in class to teach, with a conda environment that matches, and for what I believe are the same extensions installed, Intellisense does not occur.

I know that this has been asked, but I have yet to see a clear resolution, and the fact that I am using the same machine, with what I believe is the same setup, is really puzzling.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

According to your description, it is recommended that you try to check the following points:

1. Please check whether the module "`numpy`" has been successfully installed in the [VSCode environment](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments#_select-and-activate-an-environment) you are currently using. Only when this module is installed successfully, VSCode can recognize the method in the module and provide prompts.

   [image]
2. Since the code prompt and completion function in VSCode is provided by the [Python extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-python.python), it is recommended that you check whether it is installed and available.

In addition, you can try to use the extension "[Pylance](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-python.vscode-pylance)", which provides outstanding language service functions and IntelliCode, etc.

**Update**:

The code prompt and completion function provided by different language services are different. Since you want to see `randint`, `rand`, `random_integers` as an option, you can use `"python.languageServer":"Jedi",`in `settings.json`.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, numpy is properly installed in the environment being used (I have selected my python interpreter correctly).  In the terminal within VSC, things behave as expected, this is isolated to writing code via the script.  The python extension is installed, but I am not exactly sure what you mean by available.  Last but not least, what is odd is that when in the script, I can hit `np.` and its not as if various numpy modules do not appear, but it is certainly not the exhaustive solution set I have available to me on other machines.

Comment: Also, pylance is installed  but does not work either.

Comment: One other comment.  In your example above, when you type `np.random.`, do you see randint, or rand, or random_integers as an option.  My example highlights that you should see those methods, but from the screenshot, you may be replicating my issue as well.

Comment: @Btibert3 -The extension is available means that it is in the "enable" state. I updated my answer and you can refer to it.

Comment: Thanks, that looks promising (re:Jedi), but it didn't work for me.  Do I have to install anything?

Comment: @Btibert3 -Do you mean that when you use the "Jedi" language service, the automatic completion still does not work? When you set the language service to "Jedi", VSCode will automatically prompt you to install it. In addition, it is recommended that you reload VSCode after setting it.

Comment: Interesting enough, I attempted the flow of removing it from setings.json, restarting, adding again. I got a prompt to enable Microsoft's server, reloaded, and it worked.  Very curious but I appreciate your help!

Comment: But to follow up, this worked on one machine, and to my fear, I couldn't reproduce the steps on another.  This is so bizarre.

Comment: @Btibert3 -What steps do you want to reproduce? Have you tried to reset the language service on another computer? Please describe in detail or a screenshot to describe the problem you are currently experiencing. In addition, please try to use a different language service, then download and reload VSCode as prompted by the VSCode prompt box.